# Ionic/Angular reset navigation history

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-router

I'm building an Ionic 4 Angular App. In my app I have three routes `/login`, `/createAccount` and `/home`. In the `/login` route if login is successful it navigates to `/home` like this:

`this._router.navigate(['/home'], { replaceUrl: true });`

So the user can't go back to `/login` from `/home` using browser or Android back button. From `/login` it can also navigate normally to `/createAccount` so the user can return to `/login` using the back button. In `/createAccount` if account creation is successful it navigates to `/home` using again:

`this._router.navigate(['/home'], { replaceUrl: true });`

The problem is that when it navigates from `/createAccount` to `/home` the back button takes the user back to `/login` since it is in the navigation history. I need a way to reset the router after navigating to `/home`  from `/createAccount` so the user won't return to `/login` from `/home` using browser or Android back button.

Comment: out of curiosity why aren't you using router guards - is it because you also need browser level control to also not allow return to those pages?

Comment: Yes, actually I'm using route guards. I want that behavior so Ionic back button won't show there is a previous state to go back to.